# Passenger fails to run on first load, but successfully launches after single refresh

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, ruby, gem

I have a pretty simply passenger installation on my production server. It seems that every night the passenger process quits due to inactivity.

When I hit the site in the morning, passenger starts up again and will give me a fairly straightforward error that the 'sinatra' rubygem could not be loaded. When I refresh the page, the problem goes away and passenger works fine for the rest of the day.

Sinatra is a readily available gem, and I load it in after I require 'rubygems.' Any idea why passenger would fail to launch on the first try?

Comment: is there anything relevant in the apache error logs?

Comment: There are no apache errors

Answer (score 1):

Passenger stays up the whole time, but it'll allow the Rack processes which are the part executing your code to shutdown after a length of inactivity. The simplest solution is to keep at least one Rack process running. Assuming Passenger 3.x you can add this to your vhost or passenger config.

```
PassengerMinInstances 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am running 2.2.9-2. Would restart clear all the rack processes as well? Curiously, restarting the app will not cause passenger to break.

Comment: In my experience you would normally wait for Passenger to start the app and you'll get a page after half a minute or so. However I started with version 2.2.11 and went to 3.x pretty quickly. It may be a bug of some sort.Which distro are you on? There are packages for yum/apt distros. Passenger 3 is really worth the upgrade.

Comment: Have you tried using PassengerPreStart directive ?

Comment: IIRC PassengerPreStart is only available in 3.0 and up.